# Error using Soap Client in Magento

Tags: magento, soap

Hi there i am facing the following error when trying to test whether soap client is working or not:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </schema>.
Location: http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl=1
Line Number 13, Column 15:            </complexType>
```

i am hitting the following url to reach out to the wsdl

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl=1
```

i have started working with magento and trying to access its webservice.